# How to obtain the number of discontinuities

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

suppose a sawtooth function (or any other periodic function with discontinuities). I want to obtain the number of discontinuities in that function for a stated range.

For example, looking at the figure at

[image]

I should get a scalar result of 2 since there are only two discontinuities plotted in that range.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Cheers,
Felipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always the question what you consider as discontinuity. You need a `threshold` to define that. Then you can use something like the following for `yourSignal` (variable name of your data)

```
occ = sum( abs( diff( yourSignal ) ) > threshold )
```